# How to restrict the server login Prompt and redirect to home page of application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security

I have one internet publishing SharePoint Site. How to restrict the server login Prompt and redirect to home page of application

For example i have my site:

https://*****/products/pages/default.aspx
when I remove default.aspx from above URL in browser it shows authentication for user ,here what I required instead of show login prompt how to redirect to home page of site.

My requirement is login prompt should not show to  anonymous users and also anonymous users should not view any pages library and _layouts folder pages.

Here just i want to redirect to home page instead of showing login prompt because this site is published to internet and for security reasons (possibility to brute-force-attack for example) we don't want to show login prompt to users

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but until the user logs into SharePoint they will get a login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be redirected to the home page of the site without a login prompt, as a workaround, you could enable Anonymous Access for the site.

For detailed steps, please refer to:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/05/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013.html

**-------------------------Update----------------------------**

Per my test, please deactivate "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" site collection feature to make anonymous users could access pages library.

[image]

Currently, when you type the url like:https://mywebsite/products/pages/, there will be no login prompt.

Comment: Hi this is internet publishing site and Anonymous access is enabled

Comment: I have updated my reply, please check it.

Comment: Hi thanks Julie but my requirement is login prompt should not show to  anonymous users and anonymous users should not view any pages library and _layuts folder pages.

Comment: I am afraid this is a contradiction and couldn't be achieved.

Comment: This site is published to internet and for security reasons there is no login prompt should appear to anonymous users and not view any pages library pages

Comment: I try to use code to redirect the page when anonymous user access the page, however this doesn't work.